# Animal Types in Assassin's Creed: Freedom Cry

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag, assassins-creed-freedom-cry

When hunting there are a variety of animals to hunt and kill. However I just found I could hunt whales. Is there anything else I'm missing?

I know there is:

1. Rabbits
2. Lizards
3. Hammerhead Shark
4. Great White
5. Orca
6. Whale

A deer is listed as the symbol for hunting goods. Are there deer that I can kill? What creatures am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

There are many to hunt like

- Capuchin Monkey - Mistiriosa Island, Tulum, New Bone;
- Crocodiles - Tulum, Nassau, Long Bay, Isla Providencia, Matanzas;
- Jaguars - Tulum, Cape Bonavista, Principe;

And many others to Harpoon like

- Bull Shark - Check in-game map for icon;

**Full List of Animals to hunt:**

> > > **Animals -> Locations**
>
> - Crocodile -> Tulum, Nassau, Long Bay, Isla Providencia, Matanzas
> - Wild boar -> Nassau, Mariguana Island, Cape Bonavista, Great Inagua
> - Howler monkey -> Long Bay, Kingston, Cape Bonavista, Principe, Cat Island, Tortuga
> - Red Howler -> Isla Providencia
> - Monkey
> - White whale -> Online only. Appears during Community Events.
> - Killer whale -> While on ship use map to see the icons on the ocean
> - Humpback whale -> While on ship use map to see the icons on the ocean
> - Bull shark -> While on ship use map to see the icons on the ocean
> - Iguanna -> Abaco Island, Andreas Island
> - Deer -> Kingston, Satnanillas, Salt Lagoon, Principe
> - Great White Shark -> While on ship use map to see the icons on the ocean
> - Hammerhead Shark -> While on ship use map to see the icons on the ocean
> - Ocelots -> Andreas Island, Cumberland Bay, Abaco island
> - Jaguar (Black, white and normal) -> Tulum, Cape Bonavista, Principe
> - Rabbit -> Nassau, Kingston, Corozal
> - Hutia -> Long Bay, Cayman Sound, Jiguey
> - Capuchin monkey -> Mistiriosa Island, Tulum, New Bone
> - Flamingo
> - Seagulls
> - Crows

If you want to check a full complete list and their locations check [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/assassins-creed-4-black-flag/Hunting_and_Harpooning)

Comment: If you'll include where they are located I'll accept this answer.

Comment: @YoungGuilo The locations are included in the link. I'll include the locations in the answer for the ones I listed.

Comment: @YoungGuilo is it good now for you to accept?

Comment: @Lokuzt We usually try to include all the relevant info in an answer (where possible) rather than leaving it behind a link, to avoid losing the info if the linked page changed or was removed.

Comment: @Alex ok I get your point. I'll add the locations

Comment: @YoungGuilo I included the full list of animals and their Locations in the answer.

Comment: This is about Black Flag. Not the stand alone Assassin's Creed Freedom Cry.

Comment: @YoungGuilo I specifically put the link there. please have a look. Those are ALL the animals present in the game.

Comment: That is for Black Flag not Freedom Cry.

Comment: @YoungGuilo the animals are the same. Freedom Cry is just a portion of the map from AC 4. So not all animals are going to be in the DLC but still you have the idea. I don't think I deserve a downvote since there is nothing on the internet listing just the animals for the DLC.

Comment: Only put animals that I can hunt in Freedom Cry and I'll accept the answer. Otherwise the downvote remains.